# SQL Developer displaying dates incorrectly

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using my SQL Developer Version 18.1.0.095 Build 095.1630, I put a date in the table with this value: '0001-01-01'.

But after confirm the insert, I ask a select and in the return appear '0001-01-03'.

Using the same commands in SQL Developer Version 3.2.20.09 Build MAIN-09.87, 
the return is like I expected, '0001-01-01'.

SQL Developer Version 18.1.0.095 Build 095.1630

```
DATRATTIT  TRUNC(DATR TO_TIMESTAMP(DATRATTIT)         COUNT(*)
---------- ---------- ----------------------------- ---------- 
0001-01-03 0001-01-03 0001-01-03 00:00:00,000000000     237069
```

SQL Developer Version 3.2.20.09 Build MAIN-09.87

```
DATRATTIT  TRUNC(DATRATTIT) TO_TIMESTAMP(DATRATTIT)          COUNT(*)
---------- ---------------- ------------------------------ ----------
0001-01-01 0001-01-01       0001-01-01 00:00:00,000000000      237069
```

Is this a configuration issue? Something to do with NLS settings? Anybody with this problem too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting, I saw something similar a few days ago but hadn't got around to probing it further. You can see the same issue with just:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD';

select date '0001-01-01' from dual;

DATE'0001-0
-----------
 0001-01-03
```

It does seem to be a bug in the current SQL Developer though - I'm seeing it in 18.2.0.183 - and I believe the data in your table is OK - it 'just' isn't being displayed properly when you rely on implicit conversion to a string via `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

It *seems* to be related to Gregorian calendar and how SQL Developer is converting from internal representation. This query looks at the days around [the Gregorian calendar change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), and shows the client-formatted values (which are incorrect), explicit conversion to a string, and also dumps the internal representation:

```
with t (d) as (
  select date '1582-10-21' - level * interval '1' day from dual connect by level <= 10
)
select d, to_char(d, 'SYYYY-MM-DD'), dump(d, 1016) as dumped from t;

D           TO_CHAR(D,' DUMPED                                  
----------- ----------- ----------------------------------------
 1582-10-20  1582-10-20 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,14,0,0,0,0         
 1582-10-19  1582-10-19 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,13,0,0,0,0         
 1582-10-18  1582-10-18 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,12,0,0,0,0         
 1582-10-17  1582-10-17 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,11,0,0,0,0         
 1582-10-16  1582-10-16 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,10,0,0,0,0         
 1582-10-15  1582-10-15 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,f,0,0,0,0          
 1582-09-24  1582-10-04 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,4,0,0,0,0          
 1582-09-23  1582-10-03 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,3,0,0,0,0          
 1582-09-22  1582-10-02 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,2,0,0,0,0          
 1582-09-21  1582-10-01 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,1,0,0,0,0
```

As you can see, dates from 1582-10-15 are OK, those before are wrong; and they seem to be wrong in different ways depending how far you go back. It looks the same in script output and in a result grid.

Running the same query against the same DB but via SQL*Plus shows:

```
D           TO_CHAR(D,' DUMPED
----------- ----------- ----------------------------------------
 1582-10-20  1582-10-20 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,14,0,0,0,0
 1582-10-19  1582-10-19 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,13,0,0,0,0
 1582-10-18  1582-10-18 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,12,0,0,0,0
 1582-10-17  1582-10-17 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,11,0,0,0,0
 1582-10-16  1582-10-16 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,10,0,0,0,0
 1582-10-15  1582-10-15 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,f,0,0,0,0
 1582-10-04  1582-10-04 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,4,0,0,0,0
 1582-10-03  1582-10-03 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,3,0,0,0,0
 1582-10-02  1582-10-02 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,2,0,0,0,0
 1582-10-01  1582-10-01 Typ=13 Len=8: 2e,6,a,1,0,0,0,0
```

and here dates before 1582-10-15 are correctly interpreted by the client too.

I don't believe there is anything you can change to fix this; my session `NLS_CALENDAR` is already `GREGORIAN`, and choosing to skip NLS settings in the preferences didn't make any difference.

The only workaround I can see at the moment is to explicitly format your date values in your queries.

<strike>But you should raise a service request with Oracle, against SQL Developer, to get it investigated properly.</strike>

> Bug 28093149 : DATE IS RETURNED INCORRECTLY FOR 01/01/0001 - COMES BACK AS 03/01/0001

so you don't need to raise a service request... hopefully it'll be fixed in 18.3.

And it seems it's come up on the SD forum too, e.g. [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/14830227), which references that bug number.

Comment: Perfectly! This solves my problem.  I don't why the Oracle doesn't care about this issue! This seems to be a common problem for users. So, let's keep trying to fix this!
Thanks for your answer!